# CSS & JS file not loading in my cakphp appliaction

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-3.0, web-hosting

I have a cakephp website hosted on goDaddy, the css and js file are showing 404 error and the page appears blank.
i have done changes to .htaccess file in both webroot and main directory

.htaccess file in www directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and .htaccess file in webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

i'm not sure what is the cause.I checked the error log and its shows this

2020-09-02 08:06:25 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Webroot could not be found.
Request URL: /webroot/

Comment: did you try html helper:-( link:https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html)
for js file :-  $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); or $this->Html->script('/path/to/dir/jquery.min'); 
default path for js is webroot/js

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on the /webroot .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```